# Eclipse QuickFix Crashes when Importing from java.util Package

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

When I create an object from the java.util class (like ArrayList, Set, etc), QuickFix fails to suggest an import. Normally, it would suggest me to import the proper package (ie java.util.ArrayList). Instead, it does not suggest anything (when I select the object and push `ctrl` + `1`) and for some reason, my home/end keys stop functioning (interestingly, `shift` + home/end still works for highlighting, but they do not function as standalone home/end keys).

As far as I can tell, this only happens with the java.util. package. When I restart Eclipse, my home/end keys work again, but the error is reproducible.

Does anyone understand why this occurs, or even better, how to fix it? I think the error began after installing a third-party plug-in, so I may try removing the plug-in.

Also, I am working on a plug-in in the Eclipse PDE.

Comment: try to add `import java.util.*;` manually and check if there is any error, since you work on a plug-in project using PDE you may need to add the package by yourself in the manifest in Dependencies tab to use it probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced to disable proposals (in the upper list), especially if you believe those are from a third party tool.

Also, code completion has a timeout. So if some suggestion engine in Eclipse takes too much time, it is terminated by the code completion UI. That again is normally indicated by a message box, so I assume this is not your problem.

Lastly, you may want to check there is sufficient memory available in Eclipse. Otherwise the completion proposal processor may run into an out of memory and the thread is killed silently.